# Absolute element not responsive in portrait mode phone

Tags: android, ios, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have an absolute DIV that sits on top of the page. I made it responsive so it gets smaller on smaller devices and it seems to work (on laptop and on landscape mode on phones) except on portrait mode on phones (I tested it on iPhone & Samsung). I have no idea what it could be. It doesn't seem to listen to the @media queries, it only becomes smaller when I change the actual div's width and height outside of the @media queries.

You can see the div here: http://f4g.marilnu149.149.axc.nl/index.html (the logo on the top left)

CSS: (I'm using Skeleton)

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;   
  background: #201616; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #201616 0%, #7c1b1b 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #201616 0%,#7c1b1b 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #201616 0%,#7c1b1b 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#201616', endColorstr='#7c1b1b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .logo {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
  }
}

/* Larger than phablet (also point when grid becomes active) */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .logo {
    width: 4.5em;
    height: 4.5em;
  }
}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .logo {
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
  }
}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .logo {
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
  }
}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .logo {
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
  <img src="images/logo.png" />
</div>
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you are not setting any `@media` for devices *smaller than* 400px. All your `@media` query say `min-width`, thus apply for devices *greater than* the width. Thus, it uses the standard value of `width: 10em` in your primary `.logo` definition for devices narrower than 400px.

Thus, one option would be to simply change your primary definition to something smaller than 10em, e.g. 3em:

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  …
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much haha I can't believe I didn't see that! I changed it and it works now obviously! Thanks